# I am getting problems to figure out and get solutions in Reuse Patterns Using Capture Groups

Tags: javascript

so I am getting stuck trying to solve that problem in freeCodeCamp. It is about JS, to reuse Patterns using Capture groups.

> Use capture groups in reRegex to match a string that consists of only the same number repeated exactly three times separated by single spaces.

that was I've tried.

```
let repeatNum = "42 42 42";
let reRegex = /^(\d+)\s\1\s\1$/; // Change this line
let result = reRegex.test(repeatNum);
console.log(result);

// running tests
Your regex should not match the string 42\t42\t42.
// tests completed
// console output
true
```

Could someone help me to fix that regex, to not match the string 42/t42/t42, and explain me in detail? Thanks.

Comment: I'll give you a hint, `\s` matches tabs as well, you'll have to replace that with something that matches only spaces.

Comment: Use a literal space: [`/^(\d+) \1 \1$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/hlMaDT/1)

Comment: What error do you get when you try this regexp? It shouldn't be the same.

Comment: zer00ne - Thanks Very Much! That one was the correct answer. Using m (Perform multiline matching) and g (global match)  no \s.

Comment: Barmar,  I've got the answear! But the error was like: regex should not match the string 42\t42\t42. Thanks anyway!